# Firebird installation on Linux as non-root

Tags: sql, linux, firebird

I'm trying to install firebird under Linux on a machine where I don't have root access, but install.sh fails with the error "You need to be 'root' user to do this change." How can this be done?

**Edit**
I also tried building from source:

```
./configure.sh --prefix=/home/sergei/firebird
make
```

These go through fine, but then 'make install' gives:

```
(cd ../gen; ./install/makeInstallImage.sh)
You must be root to build package
```

**Edit**
To be clear, I'm only interested in running it in embedded/standalone mode (single process accessing single file), as an SQLite replacement.

Comment: You either have to modify the install script so it doesn't need root privileges or you need to obtain root privileges for long enough to install it.  If you built Firebird, maybe you can build it so that it will be installed somewhere that won't need root privileges during the install.

Comment: For embedded you should't need to install anything (AFAIK), maybe http://www.firebirdfaq.org/Firebird-Embedded-Linux-HOWTO.html can help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

short answer, you can't
Firebird full install need to create a Linux user and to activate a service, so it need root access

you can try a fakeroot, a chroot, or as said Jonathan modify the install script.
or you can try to run it in place if is for testing purpose see http://www.ib-aid.com/articles/item111

but what is your goal ?

Comment: Amended the question. I'm only interested in standalone/embedded mode.